# Version change jquery error

Tags: jquery, asp-classic, version

Hi every one I have built a web application using asp which includes a little bit of jquery from bootstap (boorstrap-dropdown.js).

for some other project which is lower version than the project I developed, I changed the version from 4 to 3.5.

Now I am getting an errors

> "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'fn': object is null or undefined"
>
> "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected"
>
> "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'collapse'"

Thank you

Comment: Can you show some code? It is difficult to see what the problem is without any code.

Comment: `$(".collapse").collapse();$('#accordion').collapse({ hide: true })`

Comment: Can you add the code to your question? It works better that way.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a conflict between jquery and other js library. Take a look to [noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) instruction to see if this fixes the problem for you.